# jQuery вывести ширину каждого элемента в span при click

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть ряд элементов, нужно вывести при клике на элемент его ширину в `<span id="response"><span>`
делаю так:

```
        $("*").click(function(){

               var value_width= $(this);
               $("#result").html(value_width.width());

      //        console.log(111);
})
```

При клике работает, но выводит всегда одно значение ширины, а у меня ряд элементов с разной шириной. Как можно поправить?

Comment: `$("#result").html($("#result").html() + " " + value_width.width());`

Comment: @igor так считает несколько несколько значений, из который верное только первое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("*").click(function(event) {
  var width = event.target.offsetWidth;
  
  $("#result").html(width);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100px; height: 20px; background: grey;"></div>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 20px; background: pink;"></div>
<div style="width: 300px; height: 20px; background: blue;"></div>

<div id="result"><div>
```